# Execute timed out js function after some time

Tags: javascript

I have a website where I put slideshow. 
When I open page my js function executes itself without the timeout and then wait 10 seconds. 
How can I make this script work properly?

```
function slider(){
    slider.navigate("next");
    setTimeout(slider,10000);
}
slider();
```

Comment: *"executes itself without the timeout and then wait 10 seconds."* Because that's exactly what you tell it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work as you expect it because you execute `slider.navigate("next")` before the timeout instead of within it. Also, by the looks of it, it seems you're attempting to create the timeout recursively, so a better alternative is to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval).

```
function slider() {
    setInterval(function () {
        slider.navigate("next");
    }, 10000);
}
slider();
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help you @MaciekMesjasz 

Comment: But this function executes itself only once :/ I wanted infinity loop

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: You must use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout` in this case @MaciekMesjasz.

Comment: No problem @MaciekMesjasz.